# Displaying name field for each array element inside a collection

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a collection (categories) and each document has a "product" field that is an array of objects (products). Each product has a "name" and a "startingCost" field. I can display each category name, but I don't know how to display every product name inside every category.

HTML:

```
<template name='categoriesList'>
    <ul class='category-grid'>
        {{ #each categories }}
            <li>{{ name }}</li>
            <!-- Display every product's name -->
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

JS:

```
Template.categoriesList.helpers({
    categories() {
        return Categories.find({});
    },
});
```

Schema:

```
{
  "_id" : "test",
  "name" : "TestNAME",
  "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-08T18:03:09.508Z"),
  "products" : [
    { "name" : "testProduct", "startingCost" : 100 },
    { "name" : "test2", "startingCost" : 200 }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should just be able to do another `{{ #each }}`

```
<template name='categoriesList'>
    <ul class='category-grid'>
        {{ #each category in categories }}
            <li>{{ category.name }}</li>
            <!-- Display every product's name -->
            <ul>
                {{ #each product in category.products }}
                <li>{{ product.name }}: ${{ product.startingCost }}</li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

Up to you if you prefer the `each products` or `each product in products` syntax. When nesting I definitely prefer the namespaced one.

Comment: Yep! I think I tried this at some point and it didn't work (I'm sure I had some simple typos or misspelled name). But it works now.

Comment: Great to hear. Want to gift me some fake internet points by accepting the answer?